# Jinja2 appending items to a list in a for loop

Tags: jinja2

I need to build a list of urls to some static images in my html. I am using jinja templates and as I understand this should work -

```
{% set urlList=[] %}
{% for i in data['a-list-of-tuples'] %}
    {% urlList.append(url_for('static', filename='sample_out/segmented/' + i[0])) %}
{% endfor %}
```

But I get the error - *jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'urlList'*

However this works -

```
{% set urlList=[] %}
{% for i in data['a-list-of-tuples'] %}
    {{ urlList.append(url_for('static', filename='sample_out/segmented/' + i[0])) }}
{% endfor %}
```

I am not sure what is happening here, can someone shed some light on this please?